# Passing a uniform color to a fragment shader (openGL ES 2.0)

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, uniform, varying

This is a strange problem.  If I try to pass a uniform color to the fragment shader, i get a compile error

```
uniform vec4 uniformColor;

void main(){
   gl_FragColor = uniformColor;
}
```

But if I pass the same uniform color to the vertex shader then pass it to the fragment shader via a varying, then it works fine..

```
    attribute vec4 position;
    uniform mat4 matrix;
    uniform vec4 uniformColor;
    varying vec4 fragmentColor; 
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = matrix * position;
        fragmentColor = uniformColor;
    }
```

and

```
varying lowp vec4 fragmentColor;
void main()
{
  gl_FragColor = fragmentColor;
}
```

this is on an iOS.

I'm a little confused as copying and pasting examples from online gives me errors.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying precision (`lowp`, `mediump`, etc.)? Also, what error message do you get on shader compilation?

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: I didn't know you needed to specify one for a uniform.  one isn't specified here: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/uniform.php

And the call to GetShader doesn't return a true status.

Comment: Yep, it's just my guess. Detailed compilation error message may be helpful.

Comment: how can i get a detailed compilation error from ios?  I'm actually compiling the code on monotouch/xamarin by tweaking their OpenGLES20Example.

Answer (score 4):

There is no default float precision qualifier for fragment shaders in OpenGL ES. A precision qualifier is required to use any floating pointer variable - it doesn't matter if it's a uniform, varying, or just a local variable. There is a default precision for vertex shaders, so you don't need to add any qualifiers there.

In OpenGL the precision qualifier is not required, which is why the example you're pointing to does not include them.

Try adding this to the top of your shader and you should be fine:

```
precision mediump float;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it was indeed related to the missing precision, but the issue is that if a uniform is shared between the vertex and fragment shaders, it must be of the same precision (at least in ES 2.0). This makes sense I suppose, because they are shared between the shaders.

And since the default precision for vertex shaders is `highp`, the precision for this uniform in the fragment shader needs to be `highp` too, as in:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform highp vec4 uniformColor;
```

Alternatively you can change the precision to mediump in the vertex shader.

The error message was very informative, when I finally noticed it: `Symbol uEcLightPos defined with different precision in vertex and fragment shaders.`